# Deserializing encrypted objects from file

Tags: c#, file, encryption, stream

I want to deserialize encrypted objects (multiple instances of the same object type) from a file, that were added during execution of a program. The objects were encrypted using CryptoStream.
However, when deserializing i cannot loop through cryptoStream as I intended.

I can serialize and encrypt the objects and the file grows with every object added.
I can also deserialize the first encrypted object. However, following objects cannot be restored.

I have tried different approaches to loop though the stream. Also I tried other cryptostreams and working around that problem.

Serializing:

```
private void EncryptObjectToFile(TraceMessage pMessage, FileInfo pFileInfo)
    {
        if (pFileInfo == null) { pFileInfo = m_LogFile; }

        m_Formatter.Serialize(m_SerializedStream, pMessage);
        m_SerializedStream.Position = 0;

        using (FileStream logfile = new FileStream(m_LogFile.FullName, FileMode.Append))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(logfile, m_Algorythm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(m_SerializedStream.ToArray(), 0, (int)m_SerializedStream.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

Deserializing:

```
private List<TraceMessage> DecryptObjectsFromFile(FileInfo pFileInfo)
    {
        List<TraceMessage> tmp = new List<TraceMessage>();

        try
        {
            READWRITELOCK.AcquireReaderLock(READERTIMEOUTS);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref READS);

            try
            {
                if (pFileInfo == null) { pFileInfo = m_LogFile; }

                m_SerializedStream.Position = 0;

                using (FileStream logfile = new FileStream(m_LogFile.FullName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(logfile, m_Algorythm.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        if (cryptoStream.CanRead)
                        {
                            while (cryptoStream.Position < cryptoStream.Length)
                            {
                                tmp.Add((TraceMessage)m_Formatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception exp) { }
            finally
            {
                READWRITELOCK.ReleaseReaderLock();
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref READS);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return tmp;
    }
```

In the end what i am trying to achieve is, to encrypt objects (multiple instances of the same object type) and add them to a file. As files can be added any time and cannot be collected in a list and then written to file, I want to add those objects to an already existing file.
Later I want to recreate each object that was encrypted and serialized to the file.

Comment: Note that during serialization you append different crypto streams to a single file. This single file in the end then contains a chain of **independently** encrypted data blocks for each trace message. However, in your deserialization you pretend the file contains just one encrypted block having all trace messages instead of a chain of multiple independently encrypted data blocks/trace messages. That's not going to work. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Either serialize all your trace messages using **one and the same** CryptoStream instance. Or, during deserialization you would need to create separate individual CryptoStreams to decrypt every trace message individually (and perhaps even possibly including the need to keep track and adjusting the file read/write pointer to make sure it is always at the beginning of the respective encrypted data block when trying to deserialize the next trace message)

Comment: I think there is very little to add to elgonzo's comments here. If you would have created a `DecryptObjectToFile` method you would have a nicely symmetric API, and you might have found out that there is no way to detect the start / end of each ciphertext. Besides that, I don't see any IV handling, so I'm just presuming that the encrypt code is insecure. Using one stream makes the most sense - unless you need to decrypt the messages separately.

Comment: Thanks very much guys for your great comments!